# How to check for required fields in object?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, object

i have example object with fields

```
name => John
surname => Dow
job => engineer
```

and output form with placeholders. some required, some not.

what is best practice for check if it requred and show error with null fields?

Comment: You need to validate form on submit, am I right?

Comment: @Tarasovych no, when making report

Comment: @DmitriySkogorev you've not provided code which makes a report. What's the report actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways actually you can do that inside of controller method or make use of Laravels Request Classes for me I prefer to use Request Classes

look below I will list the two examples

1. Validate inside the controller's method

   ```
   public function test(Request $request){
       if($request->filled('name){
            /*filled will check that name is set on the current 
              request and not empty*/

            //Do your logic here 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second way is by using the Validator Facade inside your controller

   ```
   use Validator;

   class TestController{
        public function test(Request $request){
          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
          ]);

         /*continue with your logic here if the request failed on 
           validator test Laravel will automatically redirect back 
           with errors*/
        }
   }
   ```
3. Third way my favorite one personally

   you can generate a Request class using this command

   ```
   php artisan make:request AddBookRequest
   ```

   that will generate the request class under "app/Http/Requests/AddBookRequest" , inside of any generated request class you will find two methods authorize() and rules()

in the authorized method you have to return truthy or falsy value this will detect if the current user making the request has authorization to fire this request inside of the rules method you do pretty much as you did in the Validator in the second way check the example

```
    public function authorize(){
         return true;
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'author_id' => 'required|integer'
        ];
    }
```

then simply in your controller you can use the generated request like this

```
    use App\Http\Requests\AddBookRequest;

    public function store(AddBookRequest $request){
        /* do your logic here since we uses a request class if it fails 
        then redirect back with errors will be automatically returned*/
    }
```

Hope this helps you can read more about validation at
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Answer (score 0):

I think "simple is the best", just through object and check if properties exists

Ref: [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Example:

```
if (property_exists($object, 'name')) {
     //...do something for exists property 
} else {
     //...else
}
```